# Extracting Public Page Posts from Facebook

Tags: data, web-scraping, api

I am a data science student working on my capstone research project. I am trying to collect posts from a number of public organization pages from facebook. I am looking at the graphs api and it does not appear to have an endpoint for this use case.

The page/feed requires either moderation access of the pages(which i do not have) or public page read access which requires a business application.

The CrowdTangle process is not accepting researchers outside of very specific subjects at this time.

Is there a process to get these posts that does not involve scraping page data or having people manually record each post? I do not wish to break any terms of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (2/24/2022), facebook has 2 ways to get data. CrowdTangle, and Graphs API.

CrowdTangle is made for researchers and is not taking new people

Graphs API has no avenue for research data.

there is no official solution to access public page posts on facebook as per a Facebook App Review Staff member who i got in touch with.